# DynamoDB update a counter (or insert a key)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a function that is producing `(some_key, some_value)` pairs, that I want to put in my DynamoDB. If the item with key `some_key` is already present, I want to add `some_value` to the `value` attributes. Otherwise I want to create such item. Following the example in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html) it seems that the function `if_not_exists` should do what I want. I am having troubles with the syntax, because my code returns an error:

```
>>>> table.update_item(
        Key={
            'key': my_key
        },
        UpdateExpression="set my_value = if_not_exist(my_value + :inc, :inc)",

        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': my_increment,
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: 
Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "+", near: "coocc + :val"
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'key': my_key
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET my_value = if_not_exists(my_value, :start) + :inc",

    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':inc': my_increment,
        ':start': 0,
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

The `update_item` will whether create the new item or update existing.

The UpdateExpression will check if `my_value` already exists and use existing `my_value + :inc`.

If `my_value` does not exist then it will use `:start` as initial value.

Answer (score 41):

For this type of operations you could simply use `ADD` function. 
From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html):

> ADD - Adds the specified value to the item, if the attribute does not
>   already exist. If the attribute does exist, then the behavior of ADD
>   depends on the data type of the attribute

So by using `boto3.client()` you can do the following:

```
client.update_item(
    TableName='MyTable',
    Key={'myhash': {'S': 'myvalue'}},
    UpdateExpression="ADD #counter :increment",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#counter': 'counter'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':increment': {'N': '1'}}
)
```

This will create `counter` field if it doesn't exist and it will increment it if it does exist.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer!

Comment: How can I add a begins_with condition to the key value? That is Key can begin with 'Invoke' or 'InvokeExpression'.